# sudo chown fails with operation not permitted

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, ownership

I have found similar questions here, but the answers provided to those questions do not resolve my problem.

If I do:

```
sudo chown <username> main.m
```

I get an operation not permitted error.

The general solution to prior errors was:

```
sudo chflags nouchg main.m
```

to clear a lock flag. However, after doing this, I still cannot chown the file. I have also tried:

```
chflags noschg main.m
```

in single user mode without any luck - I get an operation not permitted error.

If anyone has any thoughts, I would be interested.

Comment: What is the underlying thing that you are trying to do? Perhaps there is a reason to that file having a lock.

Comment: So I can use it as test data without placing the code in a secure helper tool, which requires extra work to debug - not impossible, but annoying enough that if I can change the attributes of the file so a secure helper tool is not necessary, that would make things a bit easier. Considering that this is just test data that was created, there is no longer any good reason for it to have a lock.

Comment: What type of filesystem is the file on?  You aren't trying to use `chown` on an NTFS/FAT filesystem are you?

Comment: @ericgorr: Most of that is over the top of my head; I'm unaware of what a secure helper tool exactly is. But as you say, it's just test data that was created; have you properly closed the test file in your code?

Comment: @Tom a helper tool is OS X's way of giving an application elevated privileges while maintaining privileges - so if an app wants to modify a secure file, for instance, it tells the (authorized) helper tool to modify the file for it. I'm guessing ericgorr wants to avoid elevating his/her application or something to avoid the rigorous debugging that comes with that.

Comment: @Zoredache Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

Comment: @Tom It wasn't my code that created the file. Yes, I am sure it was closed appropriately as I can read the file just fine after multiple reboots, etc.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex It's just more difficult and time consuming to debug code in a launchd secure helper tool then it is to have the code in a regular application. But, it appears, that may be my only option unless I can figure out how to get rid of the lock on the file so I can perform operations like chown and ditto on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mac files can be protected in <s>four</s> *three* different ways that I'm aware of:

1. Standard Unix ownerships and permissions like r/w/x for user/group/others that you see with `ls -l` and fix with `chown(1)` and `chmod(1)`.
2. File flags like `uchg` and `schg` that you see with `ls -lO` and fix with `chflags(1)`.
3. <s>The old Finder metadata "Lock bit" that you see with `GetFileInfo filename`. You can also see the presence of the Finder metadata, but not its meaning, with `ls -l@`. You can fix it with `SetFile(1)`.</s> *Never mind, this is mapped to the `uchg` flag now.*
4. Access Control Lists (ACLs) that you see with `ls -le` and fix with the ACL-related arguments to `chmod(1)`.

So let's see what's up with your file by combining all those flags to `ls`:

```
ls -lO@e main.m
```

It sounds like you already know how to deal with #1 and #2.

If you see an ACL (#4), you can fix it with the ACL-related arguments to `chmod(1)`.

If you're still stumped, update your Answer with the output from that combined `ls` command I suggested above, so we can see what's going on.

Comment: The issue does appear to be with ACLs. I do find it interesting that sudo doesn't get one around such locks. Furthermore, chmod -R -a# 0 * did remove the ACLs from most of the files in the hierarchy, but failed to remove them from some - using sudo with the chmod didn't help.